# Does kdb+ support UNC filenames?

Tags: kdb

On windows, I can load a file using a filename `` `:C:/folder/a.csv ``

Is there a way to use a UNC filename like `\\server\share\folder\a.csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
q)hsym `$"\\\\server\\share\\folder\\a.csv"
`:\\server\share\folder\a.csv
```

To list the contents :

```
q)key hsym `$"\\\\server\\share\\folder\\"
`s#a.csv
```